# How to remove the extra faces after surface reconstruction?

Tags: 3d, pcl

[image]

this portion is not part of the model

code

```cpp
  Poisson<PointNormal> poisson;
  poisson.setDepth(10);
  poisson.setSamplesPerNode(4);
  poisson.setPointWeight(2);
  poisson.setIsoDivide(10);
  poisson.setInputCloud(cloud_with_normals);

  PolygonMesh triangles;
  poisson.reconstruct(triangles);
```

Reading the points from a file, computing the normals, and performing Poisson surface reconstruction. I am trying to convert the points into a 3D model, but there is an unwanted portion that needs to be removed. How can I achieve this?